# How can I read RFID card data other than its UID using RC522 reader and RPi Pico W and MicroPython?

Tags: microcontroller, rfid, micropython, low-level, raspberry-pi-pico

I am trying to read RFID card data using RPi Pico W and RFID-RC522 reader. I tried all available tutorials and low-level mfrc522.py libraries but all it gives me is the UID of the card. I want to read data that the card has such as NDEF message which I can read/write using Android or iOS device. Following is the screenshot of the Android app that reads what card has,

[Android app screenshot that I used to create and read RFID card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaIoS.png)

This is my code for scenario 1 which was modified based on the code from this github repo : https://github.com/pimylifeup/MFRC522-python/tree/master

```
# Runner.py
import mfrc522
import utime
from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522
reader = SimpleMFRC522()

try:
    while True:
        print("Hold a tag near the reader")
        id, text = reader.read()
        print("ID: %s\nText: %s" % (id,text))
        utime.sleep_ms(1000)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    raise

########################################################################
########################################################################

# mfrc522/MFRC522.py

from machine import Pin, SPI
from os import uname


class MFRC522:

    OK = 0
    NOTAGERR = 1
    ERR = 2

    REQIDL = 0x26
    REQALL = 0x52
    AUTHENT1A = 0x60
    AUTHENT1B = 0x61
  
    PICC_ANTICOLL1 = 0x93
    PICC_ANTICOLL2 = 0x95
    PICC_ANTICOLL3 = 0x97
  

    def __init__(self, sck, mosi, miso, rst, cs,baudrate=1000000,spi_id=0):

        self.sck = Pin(sck, Pin.OUT)
        self.mosi = Pin(mosi, Pin.OUT)
        self.miso = Pin(miso)
        self.rst = Pin(rst, Pin.OUT)
        self.cs = Pin(cs, Pin.OUT)
        self.rst.value(0)
        self.cs.value(1)
        
        self.spi = SPI(spi_id,baudrate=baudrate,sck=self.sck, mosi= self.mosi, miso= self.miso)

        self.rst.value(1)
        self.init()

    def _wreg(self, reg, val):

        self.cs.value(0)
        self.spi.write(b'%c' % int(0xff & ((reg << 1) & 0x7e)))
        self.spi.write(b'%c' % int(0xff & val))
        self.cs.value(1)

    def _rreg(self, reg):

        self.cs.value(0)
        self.spi.write(b'%c' % int(0xff & (((reg << 1) & 0x7e) | 0x80)))
        val = self.spi.read(1)
        self.cs.value(1)

        return val[0]

    def _sflags(self, reg, mask):
        self._wreg(reg, self._rreg(reg) | mask)

    def _cflags(self, reg, mask):
        self._wreg(reg, self._rreg(reg) & (~mask))

    def _tocard(self, cmd, send):

        recv = []
        bits = irq_en = wait_irq = n = 0
        stat = self.ERR

        if cmd == 0x0E:
            irq_en = 0x12
            wait_irq = 0x10
        elif cmd == 0x0C:
            irq_en = 0x77
            wait_irq = 0x30

        self._wreg(0x02, irq_en | 0x80)
        self._cflags(0x04, 0x80)
        self._sflags(0x0A, 0x80)
        self._wreg(0x01, 0x00)

        for c in send:
            self._wreg(0x09, c)
        self._wreg(0x01, cmd)

        if cmd == 0x0C:
            self._sflags(0x0D, 0x80)

        i = 2000
        while True:
            n = self._rreg(0x04)
            i -= 1
            if ~((i != 0) and ~(n & 0x01) and ~(n & wait_irq)):
                break

        self._cflags(0x0D, 0x80)

        if i:
            if (self._rreg(0x06) & 0x1B) == 0x00:
                stat = self.OK

                if n & irq_en & 0x01:
                    stat = self.NOTAGERR
                elif cmd == 0x0C:
                    n = self._rreg(0x0A)
                    lbits = self._rreg(0x0C) & 0x07
                    if lbits != 0:
                        bits = (n - 1) * 8 + lbits
                    else:
                        bits = n * 8

                    if n == 0:
                        n = 1
                    elif n > 16:
                        n = 16

                    for _ in range(n):
                        recv.append(self._rreg(0x09))
            else:
                stat = self.ERR

        return stat, recv, bits

    def _crc(self, data):

        self._cflags(0x05, 0x04)
        self._sflags(0x0A, 0x80)

        for c in data:
            self._wreg(0x09, c)

        self._wreg(0x01, 0x03)

        i = 0xFF
        while True:
            n = self._rreg(0x05)
            i -= 1
            if not ((i != 0) and not (n & 0x04)):
                break

        return [self._rreg(0x22), self._rreg(0x21)]

    def init(self):

        self.reset()
        self._wreg(0x2A, 0x8D)
        self._wreg(0x2B, 0x3E)
        self._wreg(0x2D, 30)
        self._wreg(0x2C, 0)
        self._wreg(0x15, 0x40)
        self._wreg(0x11, 0x3D)
        self.antenna_on()

    def reset(self):
        self._wreg(0x01, 0x0F)

    def antenna_on(self, on=True):

        if on and ~(self._rreg(0x14) & 0x03):
            self._sflags(0x14, 0x03)
        else:
            self._cflags(0x14, 0x03)

    def request(self, mode):

        self._wreg(0x0D, 0x07)
        (stat, recv, bits) = self._tocard(0x0C, [mode])

        if (stat != self.OK) | (bits != 0x10):
            stat = self.ERR

        return stat, bits
  
    def anticoll(self,anticolN):

        ser_chk = 0
        ser = [anticolN, 0x20]

        self._wreg(0x0D, 0x00)
        (stat, recv, bits) = self._tocard(0x0C, ser)

        if stat == self.OK:
            if len(recv) == 5:
                for i in range(4):
                    ser_chk = ser_chk ^ recv[i]
                if ser_chk != recv[4]:
                    stat = self.ERR
            else:
                stat = self.ERR

        return stat, recv

    
    def PcdSelect(self, serNum,anticolN):
        backData = []
        buf = []
        buf.append(anticolN)
        buf.append(0x70)
        
        for i in serNum:
            buf.append(i)
        
        pOut = self._crc(buf)
        buf.append(pOut[0])
        buf.append(pOut[1])
        (status, backData, backLen) = self._tocard( 0x0C, buf)
        if (status == self.OK) and (backLen == 0x18):
            return  1
        else:
            return 0
    
    
    def SelectTag(self, uid):
        byte5 = 0
       
        for i in uid:
            byte5 = byte5 ^ i
        puid = uid + [byte5]
        
        if self.PcdSelect(puid,self.PICC_ANTICOLL1) == 0:
            return (self.ERR,[])
        return (self.OK , uid)
        
    def tohexstring(self,v):
        s="["
        for i in v:
            if i != v[0]:
                s = s+ ", "
            s=s+ "0x{:02X}".format(i)
        s= s+ "]"
        return s
        
            
    
    def SelectTagSN(self):
        valid_uid=[]
        (status,uid)= self.anticoll(self.PICC_ANTICOLL1)

        if status != self.OK:
            return  (self.ERR,[])
        
        if self.PcdSelect(uid,self.PICC_ANTICOLL1) == 0:
            return (self.ERR,[])

        if uid[0] == 0x88 :

            valid_uid.extend(uid[1:4])
            (status,uid)=self.anticoll(self.PICC_ANTICOLL2)

            if status != self.OK:
                return (self.ERR,[])
            rtn =  self.PcdSelect(uid,self.PICC_ANTICOLL2)
            if rtn == 0:
                return (self.ERR,[])

            if uid[0] == 0x88 :
                valid_uid.extend(uid[1:4])
                (status , uid) = self.anticoll(self.PICC_ANTICOLL3)

                if status != self.OK:
                    return (self.ERR,[])
                
                if self.PcdSelect(uid,self.PICC_ANTICOLL3) == 0:
                    return (self.ERR,[])
                
        valid_uid.extend(uid[0:5])
        
        return (self.OK , valid_uid[:len(valid_uid)-1])       
    

    def auth(self, mode, addr, sect, ser):
        return self._tocard(0x0E, [mode, addr] + sect + ser[:4])[0]
    
    def authKeys(self,uid,addr,keyA=None, keyB=None):
        status = self.ERR
        if keyA is not None:
            status = self.auth(self.AUTHENT1A, addr, keyA, uid)
        elif keyB is not None:
            status = self.auth(self.AUTHENT1B, addr, keyB, uid)
        return status
       

    def stop_crypto1(self):
        self._cflags(0x08, 0x08)

    def read(self, addr):

        data = [0x30, addr]
        data += self._crc(data)
        (stat, recv, _) = self._tocard(0x0C, data)
        return stat, recv

    def write(self, addr, data):

        buf = [0xA0, addr]
        buf += self._crc(buf)
        (stat, recv, bits) = self._tocard(0x0C, buf)

        if not (stat == self.OK) or not (bits == 4) or not ((recv[0] & 0x0F) == 0x0A):
            stat = self.ERR
        else:
            buf = []
            for i in range(16):
                buf.append(data[i])
            buf += self._crc(buf)
            (stat, recv, bits) = self._tocard(0x0C, buf)
            if not (stat == self.OK) or not (bits == 4) or not ((recv[0] & 0x0F) == 0x0A):
                stat = self.ERR
        return stat


    def writeSectorBlock(self,uid, sector, block, data, keyA=None, keyB = None):
        absoluteBlock =  sector * 4 + (block % 4)
        if absoluteBlock > 63 :
            return self.ERR
        if len(data) != 16:
            return self.ERR
        if self.authKeys(uid,absoluteBlock,keyA,keyB) != self.ERR :
            return self.write(absoluteBlock, data)
        return self.ERR

    def readSectorBlock(self,uid ,sector, block, keyA=None, keyB = None):
        absoluteBlock =  sector * 4 + (block % 4)
        if absoluteBlock > 63 :
            return self.ERR, None
        if self.authKeys(uid,absoluteBlock,keyA,keyB) != self.ERR :
            return self.read(absoluteBlock)
        return self.ERR, None

    def MFRC522_DumpClassic1K(self,uid, Start=0, End=64, keyA=None, keyB=None):
        for absoluteBlock in range(Start,End):
            status = self.authKeys(uid,absoluteBlock,keyA,keyB)
            print("{:02d} S{:02d} B{:1d}: ".format(absoluteBlock, absoluteBlock//4 , absoluteBlock % 4),end="")
            if status == self.OK:                    
                status, block = self.read(absoluteBlock)
                if status == self.ERR:
                    break
                else:
                    for value in block:
                        print("{:02X} ".format(value),end="")
                    print("  ",end="")
                    for value in block:
                        if (value > 0x20) and (value < 0x7f):
                            print(chr(value),end="")
                        else:
                            print('.',end="")
                    print("")
            else:
                break
        if status == self.ERR:
            print("Authentication error")
            return self.ERR
        return self.OK

########################################################################
########################################################################

# mfrc522/SimpleMFRC522.py

# Code by Simon Monk https://github.com/simonmonk/

from . import MFRC522
  
class SimpleMFRC522:

  READER = None
  
  KEY = [0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF]
  BLOCK_ADDRS = [8, 9, 10]
  
  def __init__(self):
    self.READER = MFRC522(spi_id=0, sck=2, miso=4, mosi=3, cs=1, rst=0)
  
  def read(self):
      id, text = self.read_no_block()
      while not id:
          id, text = self.read_no_block()
      return id, text

  def read_id(self):
    id = self.read_id_no_block()
    while not id:
      id = self.read_id_no_block()
    return id

  def read_id_no_block(self):
      (status, TagType) = self.READER.request(self.reader.REQIDL)
      if status != self.READER.OK:
          return None
      (status, uid) = self.READER.anticoll(self.READER.PICC_ANTICOLL1)
      if status != self.READER.OK:
          return None
      return self.uid_to_num(uid)
  
  def read_no_block(self):
    (status, TagType) = self.READER.request(self.READER.REQIDL)
    if status != self.READER.OK:
        return None, None
    (status, uid) = self.READER.anticoll(self.READER.PICC_ANTICOLL1)
    if status != self.READER.OK:
        return None, None
    id = self.uid_to_num(uid)
    self.READER.SelectTag(uid)
    status = self.READER.auth(self.READER.AUTHENT1A, 11, self.KEY, uid)
    data = []
    text_read = ''
    if status == self.READER.OK:
        for block_num in self.BLOCK_ADDRS:
            block = self.READER.read(block_num) 
            if block:
                data += block
        if data:
             text_read = ''.join(chr(i) for i in data)
    self.READER.stop_crypto1()
    return id, text_read
    
  def write(self, text):
      id, text_in = self.write_no_block(text)
      while not id:
          id, text_in = self.write_no_block(text)
      return id, text_in

  def write_no_block(self, text):
      (status, TagType) = self.READER.request(self.READER.REQIDL)
      if status != self.READER.OK:
          return None, None
      (status, uid) = self.READER.anticoll(self.READER.PICC_ANTICOLL1)
      if status != self.READER.OK:
          return None, None
      id = self.uid_to_num(uid)
      self.READER.SelectTag(uid)
      status = self.READER.auth(self.READER.AUTHENT1A, 11, self.KEY, uid)
      self.READER.read(11)
      if status == self.READER.OK:
          data = bytearray()
          data.extend(bytearray(text.ljust(len(self.BLOCK_ADDRS) * 16).encode('ascii')))
          i = 0
          for block_num in self.BLOCK_ADDRS:
            self.READER.write(block_num, data[(i*16):(i+1)*16])
            i += 1
      self.READER.stop_crypto1()
      return id, text[0:(len(self.BLOCK_ADDRS) * 16)]
      
  def uid_to_num(self, uid):
      n = 0
      for i in range(0, 5):
          n = n * 256 + uid[i]
      return n

########################################################################
########################################################################

# =====> OUTPUT after 3 scans

"""
Hold a tag near the reader
ID: 584194310018
Text: 
Hold a tag near the reader
ID: 584194310018
Text: 
Hold a tag near the reader
"""
```

And following code is is modified version of this github repo : https://github.com/danjperron/micropython-mfrc522 and it is still not working as I want it to work. I even tried their example code that suppose to read NDEF data but it doesn't read or write any card that I can try to read again.

```
# runner.py
from mfrc522 import MFRC522
import utime

reader = MFRC522(spi_id=0,sck=2,miso=4,mosi=3,cs=1,rst=0)

print("Bring TAG closer...")
print("")


try:
    while True:
        (status, tag_type) = reader.request(reader.REQIDL)
        
        if status == reader.OK:
            print("Card detected!")
        
        (status, uid) = reader.SelectTagSN()
        
        if status == reader.OK:
            print("Card UID: %s" % str(uid))
            
            for i in range(32):
                # get the contents of the card
                data = reader.read(i)

                # print the contents of the card
                print(f"Card contents for {i}")
                print(data[1])
                print("".join([chr(d) if 32 <= d <= 126 else "." for d in data[1]]),"\n")
            print("\n\n")

            # halt the card
            reader.stop_crypto1()
            utime.sleep_ms(500)    
    utime.sleep_ms(500)
            
except Exeption as e:
    print(f"Ee => {e}")

########################################################################
########################################################################

# mfrc522.py

from machine import Pin, SPI
from os import uname


class MFRC522:

    OK = 0
    NOTAGERR = 1
    ERR = 2

    REQIDL = 0x26
    REQALL = 0x52
    AUTHENT1A = 0x60
    AUTHENT1B = 0x61
  
    PICC_ANTICOLL1 = 0x93
    PICC_ANTICOLL2 = 0x95
    PICC_ANTICOLL3 = 0x97
  

    def __init__(self, sck, mosi, miso, rst, cs,baudrate=1000000,spi_id=0):

        self.sck = Pin(sck, Pin.OUT)
        self.mosi = Pin(mosi, Pin.OUT)
        self.miso = Pin(miso)
        self.rst = Pin(rst, Pin.OUT)
        self.cs = Pin(cs, Pin.OUT)
        self.rst.value(0)
        self.cs.value(1)
        
        self.spi = SPI(spi_id,baudrate=baudrate,sck=self.sck, mosi= self.mosi, miso= self.miso)

        self.rst.value(1)
        self.init()

    def _wreg(self, reg, val):

        self.cs.value(0)
        self.spi.write(b'%c' % int(0xff & ((reg << 1) & 0x7e)))
        self.spi.write(b'%c' % int(0xff & val))
        self.cs.value(1)

    def _rreg(self, reg):

        self.cs.value(0)
        self.spi.write(b'%c' % int(0xff & (((reg << 1) & 0x7e) | 0x80)))
        val = self.spi.read(1)
        self.cs.value(1)

        return val[0]

    def _sflags(self, reg, mask):
        self._wreg(reg, self._rreg(reg) | mask)

    def _cflags(self, reg, mask):
        self._wreg(reg, self._rreg(reg) & (~mask))

    def _tocard(self, cmd, send):

        recv = []
        bits = irq_en = wait_irq = n = 0
        stat = self.ERR

        if cmd == 0x0E:
            irq_en = 0x12
            wait_irq = 0x10
        elif cmd == 0x0C:
            irq_en = 0x77
            wait_irq = 0x30

        self._wreg(0x02, irq_en | 0x80)
        self._cflags(0x04, 0x80)
        self._sflags(0x0A, 0x80)
        self._wreg(0x01, 0x00)

        for c in send:
            self._wreg(0x09, c)
        self._wreg(0x01, cmd)

        if cmd == 0x0C:
            self._sflags(0x0D, 0x80)

        i = 2000
        while True:
            n = self._rreg(0x04)
            i -= 1
            if ~((i != 0) and ~(n & 0x01) and ~(n & wait_irq)):
                break

        self._cflags(0x0D, 0x80)

        if i:
            if (self._rreg(0x06) & 0x1B) == 0x00:
                stat = self.OK

                if n & irq_en & 0x01:
                    stat = self.NOTAGERR
                elif cmd == 0x0C:
                    n = self._rreg(0x0A)
                    lbits = self._rreg(0x0C) & 0x07
                    if lbits != 0:
                        bits = (n - 1) * 8 + lbits
                    else:
                        bits = n * 8

                    if n == 0:
                        n = 1
                    elif n > 16:
                        n = 16

                    for _ in range(n):
                        recv.append(self._rreg(0x09))
            else:
                stat = self.ERR

        return stat, recv, bits

    def _crc(self, data):

        self._cflags(0x05, 0x04)
        self._sflags(0x0A, 0x80)

        for c in data:
            self._wreg(0x09, c)

        self._wreg(0x01, 0x03)

        i = 0xFF
        while True:
            n = self._rreg(0x05)
            i -= 1
            if not ((i != 0) and not (n & 0x04)):
                break

        return [self._rreg(0x22), self._rreg(0x21)]

    def init(self):

        self.reset()
        self._wreg(0x2A, 0x8D)
        self._wreg(0x2B, 0x3E)
        self._wreg(0x2D, 30)
        self._wreg(0x2C, 0)
        self._wreg(0x15, 0x40)
        self._wreg(0x11, 0x3D)
        self.antenna_on()

    def reset(self):
        self._wreg(0x01, 0x0F)

    def antenna_on(self, on=True):

        if on and ~(self._rreg(0x14) & 0x03):
            self._sflags(0x14, 0x03)
        else:
            self._cflags(0x14, 0x03)

    def request(self, mode):

        self._wreg(0x0D, 0x07)
        (stat, recv, bits) = self._tocard(0x0C, [mode])

        if (stat != self.OK) | (bits != 0x10):
            stat = self.ERR

        return stat, bits
  
    def anticoll(self,anticolN):

        ser_chk = 0
        ser = [anticolN, 0x20]

        self._wreg(0x0D, 0x00)
        (stat, recv, bits) = self._tocard(0x0C, ser)

        if stat == self.OK:
            if len(recv) == 5:
                for i in range(4):
                    ser_chk = ser_chk ^ recv[i]
                if ser_chk != recv[4]:
                    stat = self.ERR
            else:
                stat = self.ERR

        return stat, recv

    
    def PcdSelect(self, serNum,anticolN):
        backData = []
        buf = []
        buf.append(anticolN)
        buf.append(0x70)
        
        for i in serNum:
            buf.append(i)
        
        pOut = self._crc(buf)
        buf.append(pOut[0])
        buf.append(pOut[1])
        (status, backData, backLen) = self._tocard( 0x0C, buf)
        if (status == self.OK) and (backLen == 0x18):
            return  1
        else:
            return 0
    
    
    def SelectTag(self, uid):
        byte5 = 0
       
        for i in uid:
            byte5 = byte5 ^ i
        puid = uid + [byte5]
        
        if self.PcdSelect(puid,self.PICC_ANTICOLL1) == 0:
            return (self.ERR,[])
        return (self.OK , uid)
        
    def tohexstring(self,v):
        s="["
        for i in v:
            if i != v[0]:
                s = s+ ", "
            s=s+ "0x{:02X}".format(i)
        s= s+ "]"
        return s
        
            
    
    def SelectTagSN(self):
        valid_uid=[]
        (status,uid)= self.anticoll(self.PICC_ANTICOLL1)

        if status != self.OK:
            return  (self.ERR,[])
        
        if self.PcdSelect(uid,self.PICC_ANTICOLL1) == 0:
            return (self.ERR,[])

        if uid[0] == 0x88 :

            valid_uid.extend(uid[1:4])
            (status,uid)=self.anticoll(self.PICC_ANTICOLL2)

            if status != self.OK:
                return (self.ERR,[])
            rtn =  self.PcdSelect(uid,self.PICC_ANTICOLL2)
            if rtn == 0:
                return (self.ERR,[])

            if uid[0] == 0x88 :
                valid_uid.extend(uid[1:4])
                (status , uid) = self.anticoll(self.PICC_ANTICOLL3)

                if status != self.OK:
                    return (self.ERR,[])
                
                if self.PcdSelect(uid,self.PICC_ANTICOLL3) == 0:
                    return (self.ERR,[])
                
        valid_uid.extend(uid[0:5])
        
        return (self.OK , valid_uid[:len(valid_uid)-1])       
    

    def auth(self, mode, addr, sect, ser):
        return self._tocard(0x0E, [mode, addr] + sect + ser[:4])[0]
    
    def authKeys(self,uid,addr,keyA=None, keyB=None):
        status = self.ERR
        if keyA is not None:
            status = self.auth(self.AUTHENT1A, addr, keyA, uid)
        elif keyB is not None:
            status = self.auth(self.AUTHENT1B, addr, keyB, uid)
        return status
       

    def stop_crypto1(self):
        self._cflags(0x08, 0x08)

    def read(self, addr):

        data = [0x30, addr]
        data += self._crc(data)
        (stat, recv, _) = self._tocard(0x0C, data)
        return stat, recv

    def write(self, addr, data):

        buf = [0xA0, addr]
        buf += self._crc(buf)
        (stat, recv, bits) = self._tocard(0x0C, buf)

        if not (stat == self.OK) or not (bits == 4) or not ((recv[0] & 0x0F) == 0x0A):
            stat = self.ERR
        else:
            buf = []
            for i in range(16):
                buf.append(data[i])
            buf += self._crc(buf)
            (stat, recv, bits) = self._tocard(0x0C, buf)
            if not (stat == self.OK) or not (bits == 4) or not ((recv[0] & 0x0F) == 0x0A):
                stat = self.ERR
        return stat


    def writeSectorBlock(self,uid, sector, block, data, keyA=None, keyB = None):
        absoluteBlock =  sector * 4 + (block % 4)
        if absoluteBlock > 63 :
            return self.ERR
        if len(data) != 16:
            return self.ERR
        if self.authKeys(uid,absoluteBlock,keyA,keyB) != self.ERR :
            return self.write(absoluteBlock, data)
        return self.ERR

    def readSectorBlock(self,uid ,sector, block, keyA=None, keyB = None):
        absoluteBlock =  sector * 4 + (block % 4)
        if absoluteBlock > 63 :
            return self.ERR, None
        if self.authKeys(uid,absoluteBlock,keyA,keyB) != self.ERR :
            return self.read(absoluteBlock)
        return self.ERR, None

    def MFRC522_DumpClassic1K(self,uid, Start=0, End=64, keyA=None, keyB=None):
        for absoluteBlock in range(Start,End):
            status = self.authKeys(uid,absoluteBlock,keyA,keyB)
            print("{:02d} S{:02d} B{:1d}: ".format(absoluteBlock, absoluteBlock//4 , absoluteBlock % 4),end="")
            if status == self.OK:                    
                status, block = self.read(absoluteBlock)
                if status == self.ERR:
                    break
                else:
                    for value in block:
                        print("{:02X} ".format(value),end="")
                    print("  ",end="")
                    for value in block:
                        if (value > 0x20) and (value < 0x7f):
                            print(chr(value),end="")
                        else:
                            print('.',end="")
                    print("")
            else:
                break
        if status == self.ERR:
            print("Authentication error")
            return self.ERR
        return self.OK


########################################################################
########################################################################
 
# =====> OUTPUT after 1 scan which shows that it is reading data I would like it to read but not in correct format

"""
Bring TAG closer...

Card UID: [4, 177, 191, 146, 133, 50, 128]
Card contents for 0
[4, 177, 191, 130, 146, 133, 50, 128, 165, 72, 0, 0, 225, 16, 18, 0]
......2..H...... 

Card contents for 1
[146, 133, 50, 128, 165, 72, 0, 0, 225, 16, 18, 0, 1, 3, 160, 16]
..2..H.......... 

Card contents for 2
[165, 72, 0, 0, 225, 16, 18, 0, 1, 3, 160, 16, 68, 3, 30, 209]
.H..........D... 

Card contents for 3
[225, 16, 18, 0, 1, 3, 160, 16, 68, 3, 30, 209, 1, 26, 84, 2]
........D.....T. 

Card contents for 4
[1, 3, 160, 16, 68, 3, 30, 209, 1, 26, 84, 2, 101, 110, 84, 104]
....D.....T.enTh 

Card contents for 5
[68, 3, 30, 209, 1, 26, 84, 2, 101, 110, 84, 104, 105, 115, 32, 105]
D.....T.enThis i 

Card contents for 6
[1, 26, 84, 2, 101, 110, 84, 104, 105, 115, 32, 105, 115, 32, 109, 121]
..T.enThis is my 

Card contents for 7
[101, 110, 84, 104, 105, 115, 32, 105, 115, 32, 109, 121, 32, 108, 111, 110]
enThis is my lon 

Card contents for 8
[105, 115, 32, 105, 115, 32, 109, 121, 32, 108, 111, 110, 103, 32, 116, 101]
is is my long te 

Card contents for 9
[115, 32, 109, 121, 32, 108, 111, 110, 103, 32, 116, 101, 120, 116, 33, 33]
s my long text!! 

Card contents for 10
[32, 108, 111, 110, 103, 32, 116, 101, 120, 116, 33, 33, 33, 254, 0, 0]
 long text!!!... 

Card contents for 11
[103, 32, 116, 101, 120, 116, 33, 33, 33, 254, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
g text!!!....... 

Card contents for 12
[120, 116, 33, 33, 33, 254, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
xt!!!........... 

Card contents for 13
[33, 254, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
!............... 

Card contents for 14
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
................ 

Card contents for 15
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
................ 

Card contents for 16
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
................ 

Card contents for 17
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
................ 

Card contents for 18
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
................ 

Card contents for 19
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
................ 

Card contents for 20
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
................ 

Card contents for 21
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
................ 

Card contents for 22
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
................ 

Card contents for 23
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
................ 

Card contents for 24
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
................ 

Card contents for 25
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
................ 

Card contents for 26
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
................ 

Card contents for 27
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
................ 

Card contents for 28
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
................ 

Card contents for 29
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
................ 

Card contents for 30
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
................ 

Card contents for 31
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
................ 

"""
```

I am trying to read the data and not UID but I am unable to read it and the reason I want data is that the RFID cards can be recycled for other purposes if we do not stick with UID. The data that is in card can be read to trigger different tasks.